# `Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension` error while bundle install in alpine-3.7 docker image

Tags: ruby, docker, rubygems, alpine-linux

I have created a docker image using alpine-3.7 and ruby-2.5 (bundler-2.1.2). While installing the ruby gems, using `bundle install`, I am getting the below error.

```
Fetching jaro_winkler 1.5.2
Installing jaro_winkler 1.5.2 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
An error occurred while installing jaro_winkler (1.5.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install jaro_winkler -v '1.5.2' --source 'https://testrepos.net/api/gems/rubygems/'` succeeds before bundling
```

I also tried `gem install jaro_winkler -v '1.5.2' --source 'https://testrepos.net/api/gems/rubygems/'` but got the following error.

```
Fetching jaro_winkler-1.5.2.gem
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jaro_winkler:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Comment: Did you try to run `gem install jaro_winkler -v '1.5.2' --source 'https://cernerrepos.net/api/gems/rubygems/'` before running `bundle install`?

Comment: I did but got the following error. `ERROR:  Error installing jaro_winkler:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

Answer (score 8):

Adding `RUN apk update && apk add --virtual build-dependencies build-base` to the docker file and then running `bundle install` resolved the issue.

```
# below line is just an example, and it might not work for you, use the correct repo name and image name
FROM testrepos.net/ruby:2.5-alpine3.7
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
RUN /bin/sh
RUN apk update && apk add --virtual build-dependencies build-base
RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle install
```